# before calling application _ start event database has been created?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know before asp call this method , database has been created and is ready?
you know this method run when someone visit website for first time. if someone visit the site its mean website has been created before right? can you tell me about it?
its driving me crazy. thank you.

Comment: It doesn't have to be when a database is created, application_start is called when the app starts for the first time. Documentation is here -> msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx#Overview

Comment: @Zee i mean database has been created before this method calling?